# Sidekiq: How to get a job to fire once on (re)deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a few jobs that query some external APIs. I have two types of jobs.

One job to gather a large amount of data.

And another to keep the data updated every fifteen minutes.

I would like the bulk job to fire one time on deployment to collect that bulk data, then lay dormant while the update job executes on set intervals to keep the data topped off.

How does one set a job to fire one time on deployment?

**Edit:**

This is what I've tried so far.

With a rake task

```
# application.rb
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.load_tasks # Load our Event collection task.
  Rake::Task['initialize_event_collection:build_eventbrite'].invoke
  Rake::Task['initialize_event_collection:build_meetup'].invoke
end


namespace :initialize_event_collection do
  desc "This task fetches Meetup and Eventbrite events in bulk on startup."

  task :build_eventbrite do
    FetchEventbriteJob.perform_later
  end
  task :build_meetup do
    FetchMeetupJob.perform_later
  end
end
```

It *looks* like it starts but then it doesn't really go anywhere:

```
Redis and Puma stuff above...
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:36.829Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.3 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.449Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.449Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.450Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.456Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Loading Schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.456Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Schedule empty! Set Sidekiq.schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.457Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Schedules Loaded
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.463Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Reloading Schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.464Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Loading Schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.464Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Scheduling UpdateEventbriteJob {"cron"=>"*/15 * * * *", "class"=>"UpdateEventbriteJob"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:37.969Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Scheduling UpdateMeetupJob {"cron"=>"*/15 * * * *", "class"=>"UpdateMeetupJob"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.353Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Scheduling UpdateStatusJob {"cron"=>"0 0 * * *", "class"=>"UpdateStatusJob"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.383Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Schedules Loaded
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.383Z 1 TID-gq6vufr4k INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.610Z 1 TID-gq6wf5uic FetchEventbriteJob JID-6803f9b93ce89e02ccb73d1d INFO: start
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.623Z 1 TID-gq6wf5vp4 FetchEventbriteJob JID-79b83c0d2be3c647d8c8b52e INFO: start
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.652Z 1 TID-gq6wf5v68 FetchMeetupJob JID-5c65f2262582a1e278b9986d INFO: start
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.752Z 1 TID-gq6wf5tx8 FetchMeetupJob JID-cedc08eb695de6c14e371259 INFO: start
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:20:38.854Z 1 TID-gq6wf5uqo FetchEventbriteJob JID-227879792a37d35bb6815a5d INFO: start
web_1      | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1      | * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
web_1      | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
web_1      | * Environment: development
web_1      | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1      | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

---

I've tried to call a method that calls the same job:

```
# application.rb
config.after_initialize do
  Event.build_eventbrite
  Event.build_meetup
end

# event.rb
def build_eventbrite
  FetchEventbriteJob.perform_later
end

def build_meetup
  FetchMeetupJob.perform_later
end
```

It looks like Rails doesn't like this approach

```
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-21T02:29:23.858Z 1 TID-gqzwqq0wc INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.3 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/"}
sidekiq_1  | undefined method `build_eventbrite' for Event (call 'Event.connection' to establish a connection):Class
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing'
sidekiq_1  | /work_project/config/application.rb:29:in `block in <class:Application>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
sidekiq_1  | /work_project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:242:in `require'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:242:in `boot_system'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:17:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:17:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
work_project_sidekiq_1 exited with code 1
web_1      | Exiting
web_1      | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing': undefined method `build_eventbrite' for Event (call 'Event.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
web_1      |  from /work_project/config/application.rb:29:in `block in <class:Application>'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
web_1      |  from /work_project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
web_1      |  from /work_project/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
web_1      |  from /work_project/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
web_1      |  from /work_project/config.ru:in `new'
web_1      |  from /work_project/config.ru:in `<main>'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
web_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
web_1      |  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
web_1      |  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
work_project_web_1 exited with code 1
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.0
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.4
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/lib/redis/data'
  # To run jobs in development, uncomment out this block
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    env_file: .env
    links:
      - db
      - redis
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/work_project
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
```

Comment: What does your deployment setup look like ?

Comment: @DavidGross, I amended my post with more information.

Comment: The rake tasks looks like its working. Do you have Sidekiq::Web mounted in your routes? You can check if the jobs are queuing up.

Comment: I don't have jobs mounted in my routes. I use the `sidekiq-scheduler` gem that just assigns them cron jobs or I just just fire them off with `.perform_now`. Yet, it just idles there in console as you can see above but I don't get any data flowing through my console like I would if I were just to call in manually inside my terminal. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little overkill, but you could look at the [Sidekiq Scheduler Gem](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler). It offers a lot, like regular scheduling of jobs, but also includes an option to trigger on startup.